# Why don't new (service) accounts added by `dscl` don't show up in `/etc/paswd` after system reboot?

Tags: mojave, user-account, open-directory

I've added some new (service) accounts to my macOS system using `dscl` with names like `_www` to run installed services.

However, while the system recognizes the account names in commands (the accounts actually exist), they don't show up in `/etc/passwd` like the standard `_www` account.

How can I make my `dscl`-created accounts show up in `/etc/passwd` for consistency?

Comment: macOS only uses /etc/passwd early in the boot process and in single-user mode, so there's no need to add locally-created accounts to it. It's not needed, it's not relevant, don't worry about it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - Thank you. What determines, if an account goes into `/etc/passwd` or not? Having a Linux background, I've always found `/etc/passwd` convenient for listing all user accounts.

Comment: As far as I know, only the accounts put there by the macOS installer (and most of them aren't needed, I suspect Apple just replicates them there because it's easier than figuring out which ones *need* to be there). On macOS, the real accounts database is in /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users; you should ignore /etc/passwd.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - and the only way to read that macOS specific account database is using `dscl`? :-)

Comment: There are other commands, like `id`, that can give you information derived from it, and if you're root you can access the raw files (but it's restricted by privacy controls in the latest versions). But I'd say that `dscl` is the *right* way to access it. Also, for lookups, you should use the /Search node (e.g. `dscl /Search -read /Users/fred`) because it'll also search any network directories you're using.

Comment: @GordonDavisson - How do you know this information regarding `/etc/passwd`? Do you have a good source on macOS internals?

Comment: I've been working with macOS, and messing with its internals, for quite a while; most of the actual references I've used are now out of date. But in this case, there's a (not completely correct, but close) comment at the beginning of /etc/passwd itself.